# Node or Taxonomy reference field with "Add new item" on node creation page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax, nodes

I would like to include an "Analyst" Reference field in a content type and allow users to create a new option without needing to leave the Add node page.  So it would be a drop-down with an "Add New Analyst" button.  So a pop-up or an iframe or something so the user doesn't have to leave the page to add a new option and then start over from scratch.

The "Analyst" could be a separate content type or even taxonomy term with multiple fields.

I would use Select (or other) module, but it doesn't support Node reference or taxonomy with multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For node reference fields, I use [References Dialog](https://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) to include a link for adding the referenced node. Looks like they are working on taxonomy references.